# Forge DWG file translation

Tags: autodesk-forge

When translating and downloading *DWG* files from a server, the downloaded content contains different folders like

```
24d925af-2793-8061-0b78-6eba65e7eba8_f2d,   
382a3ef0-6066-5db8-8f62-79017ae1e777_f2d, 
4215b4a9-11b7-7e99-6d6f-4f124effceea_f2d etc.
```

which each contain a `primaryGraphics.f2d` file.
What is the use of these different folders and the `primaryGraphics.f2d` files in them?

Answer (score 0):

Each f2d file represents a layout in the original DWG file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might probably refer to what https://extract.autodesk.io/ provided. The code workflow is to get the urn of the derivative,
https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/blob/838b63f1f76668081c789d9962b93a0f97d9555c/server/bubble.js#L110

```
self.extractPathsFromGraphicsUrn (node.urn, item) ;
```

and get out the section of guid ***_f2d
https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/blob/838b63f1f76668081c789d9962b93a0f97d9555c/server/bubble.js#L391

```
var basePath =urn.slice (0, urn.lastIndexOf ('/') + 1) ;
```

finally this guid ***_f2d will be used for the folder of the zip.

The urn of the derivative can be achieved by https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/ .

The following is the example of one of my test models:

Hope it helps.

[image]